# Pasar valor de parámetro desde url hasta html

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-html-service

Tengo problemas para pasar el valor de una variable desde un parámetro en la url hasta un html en appscript

Muestro un ejemplo abajo:

URL con parámetro:

```
https://script.google.com/a/<#######>/s/<script>/exec?clave=hola
```

codigo.gs

```
function doGet(e) 
{
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  template.clave=e.parameter.clave

  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Admisiones')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <label for="id-cfolio" id="id-lfolio">Folio automático  : </label>
<input type="text" size="6"  id="id-cfolio" readonly  />
    </body>
    </html>
```

JavaScript.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
document.getElementById("id-cfolio").value = clave; 

}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor revisa [ask]. Te lo menciono porque en tu pregunta dices que tienes problemas y pones un ejemplo pero no indicas que es lo que esperas que realice el código del ejemplo y el código del archivo JavaScript.html aparemente está sobrando.

Comment: Recién encontré que se publicó también en [so]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798984/i-send-parameter-value-from-url-to-html-in-appsscript-but-does-not-recognize-it pero con otro nombre de usuario. No está permitido que una misma persona tenga varias cuentas. Solicita que las unifiquen. Mas detalles en http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

En el código incluído en la pregunta, la plantilla Index.html no incluye una impresión de scriptlet (printing scriptlet):

```
<?= ... ?>
```

Nota: El archivo JavaScript.html sale sobrando.

## Explicación

El servicio HTML de Google Apps Script incluye el uso de plantillas para crear páginas dinámicas. Estas pueden incluir secuencias de comando y HTML. Las plantillas de Apps Script pueden incluir tres tipos de etiquetas llamadas Scriptlets. Dentro de un scriptlet, se puede escribir cualquier secuencia de comandos que funcionaria en un archivo normal de Apps Script y llamar variables.

## Ejemplo

El siguiente código es una aplicación web creada usando Google Apps Script. Toma del URL parámetro `mensaje` y lo publica en el cuerpo de una página HTML.

Ejemplo de URL correspondiente a

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/script-id/dev?mensaje=Hola
```

Código.gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  // Primero, tomar la plantilla
  var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  // Segundo, asignar el valor del parámetro mensaje del URL a un parámetro  
  // de la plantilla       
  t.mensaje = e.parameter.mensaje;

  // Tercero, evaluar la plantilla.
  return t.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?= mensaje ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Referencias

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates
- [Respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35758490/1595451) de [Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1677912/mogsdad) a https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738587/pass-url-parameter-into-web-app-script

Answer (score 0):

Intenta reemplazando esta línea:

```
<input type="text" size="6"  id="id-cfolio" readonly  />
```

Por esta:

```
<input type="text" size="6"  id="id-cfolio" />
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el sentido de hacer el intento que propones?