# Capturar datos en Spreadsheet usando button onclick y direccionar a otra pagina con button onclick "Appscript"

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-html-service

Actualmente estoy tratando de capturar información en una `spreadsheet` con `button onclick` pero no ha sido posible genera el siguiente error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Adicionalmente se requiere que al presionar este botón me direccione a una segunda página para continuar con captura de más información.

Realicé el ejercicio de captura de información con la función `onsumbmit` y sí se logra la captura pero no logré el paso hacia otra página.

1. Ejercicio con `onbutton`

Codigo.gs

```
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Seleccion_Actividad").evaluate().setTitle("Iniciativas Operaciones");

}

 function doPost(e){
  Logger.Log(e);
}

function EnvioTipoActividad(info){
  var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.openById('124cf1pMBO4dV2DgLxsPd3xa4XkZzEp4MhvA4xNnyXic').getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow([info.iniciativa]);
  return 'Exitoso';

}
```

Archivo .Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    </head>
  <body>
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Seleccione Tipo de Actividad :</legend>  

        <label><input type="radio" name="actividad"    value="01"required> Iniciativa </label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="actividad"    value="02"> Proyecto</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="actividad"    value="03"> Requerimiento</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="actividad"    value="04"> Idea</label><br><br>
        <!--<input type="submit" value="Continuar"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar"/>-->

          <button onclick='EnvioTipoActividad(e)'>Continuar</button>      


    </fieldset> 
  <script>  

      function EnvioTipoActividad(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var info= {
        iniciativa: e.target['actividad'].value,
      }

     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
         console.log(response);
         }).EnvioTipoActividad(info);
    }

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

2.Ejercicio con `onsubmit`:

Archivo Código.gs

```
function doGet() {
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Seleccion_Actividad").evaluate().setTitle("Iniciativas Operaciones");

}

  function doPost(e){
  Logger.Log(e);
}

function EnvioTipoActividad(info){
  var sheet =SpreadsheetApp.openById('124cf1pMBO4dV2DgLxsPd3xa4XkZzEp4MhvA4xNnyXic').getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow([info.iniciativa]);
  return 'Exitoso';

}
```

Archivo.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

     <form onsubmit="EnvioTipoActividad(event)">
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Seleccione Tipo de Actividad :</legend>  

        <label><input type="radio" name="actividad"    value="01"required> Iniciativa </label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="actividad"    value="02"> Proyecto</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="actividad"    value="03"> Requerimiento</label><br>
        <label><input type="radio" name="actividad"    value="04"> Idea</label><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Continuar"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar"/>

     </fieldset> 
    </form>

 <script>

function EnvioTipoActividad(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var info= {
        iniciativa: e.target['actividad'].value,
      }

     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(response) {
         console.log(response);
         }).EnvioTipoActividad(info);
    }
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

HTML Seleccion Elemento

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="EnvioTipoElemento(event)">
     <fieldset>
       <legend>Seleccione Tipo de Elemento :</legend>  


        <input list="elemento" name="elemento">
          <datalist id="elemento">
            <option value="AM">
            <option value="DARUMA">
            <option value="UNOE">
            <option value="SAP">
          </datalist>
        <input type="submit" value="Continuar">
        <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">

    </fieldset>
   </form> 


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

El error significa que a la variable `e` no se le ha asignado un valor u objeto en el código del lado del cliente.

Hay varias maneras de pasar una variable u objetos del código del lado del servidor al código del lado del cliente. Explico algunas de estas formas en

- mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13857/65) a [Pasar valor de parámetro desde url hasta html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13811/65)
- mi [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/99567/65) a [Botón que hace ejecutar una Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/99483/65)