# Crear un botón que onClick envíe un email

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, email, google-apps-script

Me "copié" un código de Internet para crear una implementación y consultar unos datos de una hoja de cálculo. He estado navegando mucho para sacar este tema porque soy nuevo en Google Apps Script y mucho más en HTML. Así que he querido crear una hoja html para editar un hoja de cálculo. El caso es el siguiente.

En el excel una de las celdas es un email, y otra es una URL. El objetivo es que al pinchar en el botón, le llegue al email de la celda el enlace que hay en la otra celda.

Este código es para un listado de cosas. Y cada cosa se añade en una celda dentro de una misma línea. Luego se puede buscar cada cosa o bien acceder a todo el listado completo.

Os dejo mi código HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <!-- Vue.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div id="app" class="container">
        
        <h1> Menú </h1>
        
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Nombre </th>
                    <th> Descripción </th>
                    <th> Categoría </th>
                    <th> </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>                                
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" v-model="item_menu_temp.nombre" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese una descripción" v-model="item_menu_temp.descripcion" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" v-model="item_menu_temp.categoria">
                            <option value=""> Ingrese la categoría </option>
                            <option v-for="c in categorias" v-bind:value="c[0]"> {{ c[0] }} </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="addItemMenu()" v-bind:disabled="!validarItemMenu(item_menu_temp)"> Agregar </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" v-model="texto_busqueda" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" v-on:click="getMenuFiltrado()"> Buscar </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" v-on:click="getMenu()"> Traer todo </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr v-for="item in menu">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre" v-model="item.nombre" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese una descripción" v-model="item.descripcion" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" v-model="item.categoria">
                            <option value=""> Ingrese la categoría </option>
                            <option v-for="c in categorias" v-bind:value="c[0]"> {{ c[0] }} </option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="<?= saludo ?>" target="_blank">LINK a registro</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="updateItemMenu(item)" v-bind:disabled="!validarItemMenu(item)"> Modificar </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="deleteItemMenu(item)"> Eliminar </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </div>
    
    <script>
        
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',            
            data: function(){
                return {
                    categorias: [],
                    item_menu_temp: {
                        nombre: '',
                        descripcion: '',
                        categoria: ''
                    },
                    menu: [],
                    texto_busqueda: ''
                }
            },
            created: function(){
                this.getCategorias();
            },
            methods: {
                getCategorias: function(){
                    let that = this;
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(categorias){
                        that.categorias = categorias;
                    }).getCategorias();
                },
                addItemMenu: function(){
                    let that = this;
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
                        alert("El registro se ha guardado en el menú.");
                        that.item_menu_temp.nombre = "";
                        that.item_menu_temp.descripcion = "";
                        that.item_menu_temp.categoria = "";
                    }).addItemMenu(that.item_menu_temp);
                },
                validarItemMenu: function(p_item){
                    return (
                        p_item.nombre.split(" ").join("") != "" &&
                        p_item.descripcion.split(" ").join("") != "" &&
                        p_item.categoria.split(" ").join("") != ""
                    );
                },
                getMenu: function(){
                    let that = this;
                    that.menu = [];
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(menu){
                        that.menu = [];
                        for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++)
                        {
                            that.menu.push({
                                ID:  menu[i][0],
                                nombre: menu[i][1],
                                descripcion: menu[i][2],
                                categoria: menu[i][3]
                            });
                        }
                    }).getMenu();
                },
                getMenuFiltrado: function(){
                    let that = this;
                    that.menu = [];
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(menu_filtrado){
                        that.menu = [];
                        if(menu_filtrado.length > 0){
                            for(let i = 0; i < menu_filtrado.length; i++)
                            {
                                that.menu.push({
                                    ID:  menu_filtrado[i][0],
                                    nombre: menu_filtrado[i][1],
                                    descripcion: menu_filtrado[i][2],
                                    categoria: menu_filtrado[i][3]
                                });
                            }
                         }else{
                             alert('La búsqueda no ha traído resultado');
                         }
                    }).getMenuFiltrado(that.texto_busqueda);
                },
                updateItemMenu: function(p_item){
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
                        alert("El registro se ha guardado en el menú.");
                    }).updateItemMenu(p_item);
                },
                deleteItemMenu: function(p_item){
                    let that = this;
                    if(confirm("Está segura/o que desea eliminar este ítem?")){
                       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
                           alert("El registro se ha eliminado del menú.");
                           that.getMenu();
                       }).deleteItemMenu(p_item);
                    }
                }
            }
        });   
        
    </script>
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

El caso es que en la línea donde rescato la variable "saludo"

```
<td>
                      <a href="<?= saludo ?>" target="_blank">LINK a registro</a>
                    </td>
```

he probado a añadir un botón, eso sin problema, pero el problema es al añadir la función. ya que he puesto en la parte del script:

```
SendEmail: function(p_item){
                    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(SendEmail).SendEmail(p_item);
                },
```

Pero no sé porqué no funciona.

Luego en Google Apps Script la función sendemail

```
function SendEmail (p-item){
  let ws = SS.getSheetByName("Listado user");
  GmailApp.sendEmail("miemail@midominio.com", "asunto", "Mensaje");
}
```

Comment: O lo implementas con backend o usas una API como la de [formspree](https://formspree.io/). Obviamente usando una API dependerás de un servicio externo y no tendrás ningún control sobre el modo en el que viene efectuado el envío.

Comment: Hola,  Ariel Montes, Gracias por responder tan pronto. Eso es lo que estoy tratando de hacer, llamar a una función que esté dentro de GAS.

Comment: En lugar de incluir el código completo deberías incluir un [mcve] (falta el código donde llamas al HTMLService y además de que se incluye demasiado código que es innecesario para los efectos de enviar una email con Google Apps Script al hacer clic en un botón del lado del cliente)

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que has escogido un código "bastante" complicado para alguien que está empezando con Google Apps Script y HTML ya que está usando de un vue.js no de the JavaScript "puro" / "vainilla".

Ejemplo mínimo

Te sugiero empezar con el siguiente ejemplo que muestra el código del lado del servidor y del lado del cliente para una aplicación web que muestra un botón que al hacer click en él enviará un mensaje de correo electrónico.

Por simplicidad y debido que esto está enfocado a principiantes se hace uso del atributo `onclick` en lugar de una "event listener".

Código.gs

```
function doGet(e){
  return HTMLService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function sendEmail(){
  const recipient = 'alguien@example.com';
  const asunto = 'Envío de mensaje usando Google Apps Script';
  const body = 'Poner aquí el texto del cuerpo del mensaje'; 
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,body);
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <button onclick="google.script.run.sendEmail()">Enviar email</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Para utilizar el código anterior deberá primero ser publicado como aplicación web. Para esta tarea en lo personal prefiero el uso del editor anterior pues nos permite fácilmente reutilizar el mismo URL cuando se hagan cambios a la aplicación.

Cuando logres que el botón funcione te sugiero intentar incluir un `<form>...</form>` . En la documentación oficial se incluye un ejemplo completo (abajo se incluyen los enlaces)

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms

Relacionado

- [Botón que hace ejecutar una Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/99483/65)
- [Capturar datos en Spreadsheet usando button onclick y direccionar a otra pagina con button onclick "Appscript"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142784/65)

Comment: Mil gracias, Rubén. En efecto, me he complicado de más. Escogí esto porque pensaba que iba a ser más fácil retocarlo que hacerlo desde cero. He utilizado parte de lo que me has dicho. y ahora ya he conseguido enlazar el envío de email desde el botón. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: No hay de que @PAbloMol. Por favor lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Si, te he votado, pero es que dice que como no tengo reputación, se registran pero no lo ves. Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: También podrías aceptar mi respuesta :)