# Iniciar sesion y enviar datos con GAS

Tags: javascript, login, post, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-html-service

Estoy trabajando con un código que debería validar un usuario y abrir un formulario con datos filtrados para ese usuario. Para abrir el formulario luego de validar use un método dinámico que publicaron aquí y me funciona bien:

```
var rutaWeb = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
function doGet(e) {
 var page = e.parameter.p || "myPrueba"; 
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page).evaluate()
 .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

en el index:

```
function abrirUrl(url) {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.target = "_blank";
        a.href = url;
        a.click();            
    }

    var url = "<?!= rutaWeb + '?p=Inicio' ?>";

function abrirInicio(){
        var tname = document.getElementById("nomcon").value;
        abrirUrl(url);

        //enviar tname???
    }
```

He intentado con varias opciones de aqui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit
 pero no me funcionan.

Estoy haciendo todo mal o que me falta??

Answer (score 2):

Una de las cosas que te faltó fue pasar la variable global a la plantilla.

Ejemplo:

Código.gs

```
// Variables globales
var mensaje = 'Hola mundo';

// Devuelve una página web
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  template.mensaje = mensaje; // Esta es la línea de código faltante

  var html = template.evaluate();
  return html;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?!= mensaje ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Preguntas relacionadas

- [Pasar valor de parámetro desde url hasta html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13811/65)

Answer (score 2):

Para enviar la información del usuario validado me dio mejor resultado usar CacheService.getUserCache() declarandola global en el .gs:

```
var rutaWeb = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
var cache = CacheService.getUserCache();

function doGet(e) {
 var page = e.parameter.p || "myPrueba"; 
 var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(page);

 var user = cache.get("USER");
 template.user = user;

 var html = template.evaluate()
            .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
 return html;
}
```

Como necesito el nombre del usuario que inicio sesión recupere los datos al validarlo:

index.html

```
function abrirInicio(){
 var user = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler().getUser(document.forms[0]);
 abrirUrl(url);        
}
```

Codigo.gs

```
function getUser(e){
 cache.put("USER", e.nomcon); 
}
```

Bienvenido.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Bienvenido <?!= user ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```