# Cómo renderizar varias listas html con Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, html5, script, google-apps-script

Soy nuevo en el mundo de *Apps Script* actualmente estoy diseñando una **WepApp** la cual se compone de listas en html que conectan a Mysql, cuando pruebo individualmente mis listas pintan correctamente y sus iconos modifican y actualizan los datos, sin embargo **el problema es** cuando uno todas mis listas y las llamo a través de sus correspondiente url solo me pinta la ultima las otras quedan en blanco. Por ejemplo de 10 listas llamo la #2 el log me dice que llame la 10; llamo la 5 pasa igual y si llamo la 10 me pinta los datos y se dejan modificar.
Dentro de lo que he buscado encuentro que mi problema radica en la manera como renderizo mis paginas pero no logro encontrar el camino correcto, por lo cual pido su apoyo.

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template ;
  var view = e.parameters.v;

  if(view == null){
    template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index");
  }if(view == "Index"){
    template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Index");
  }if(view != null && view != "Index"){
    template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(view);
  }

  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Documental')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);


}

function getTemplate(view){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(view);
}
```

y con este método JavaScript conecto mi cod appscript para pasarlo a mi html

```
window.onload = function () {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(run_This_On_Success)
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .readAreaPRE();
};
function onFailure(error) {
  var div = document.getElementById("output");
  div.innerHTML = "ERROR: " + error.message;
}
function run_This_On_Success (readAreaPRE) {

  let table = $("#selectTable");
  table.find("tbody tr").remove();
  table.append("<tr><td>" + "</td><td>" + "</td></tr>");

  readAreaPRE.forEach(function (e1, readAreaPRE) {    
    table.append(
      "<tr><td>" +
        e1[0] +
        "</td><td>" +
        e1[1] +
        "</td><td>" +
        "<p><a class='modal-trigger' id=" + e1[0] + " href='#modal1' onclick='capturaid("+e1[0]+",&#39;"+ e1[1]+"&#39;)'><i class='material-icons'>edit</i></a>" +
        "<a class='modal-trigger' href='#modal3' onclick='capturaidsup("+e1[0]+")'><i class='material-icons'>delete</i></a></p>" +
        "</td></tr>"
    );
  });
};


  function capturaidsup(dato1){  
 $("#delAreaPRE").val(dato1)
 }

 function capturaid(item1,item2) {
  $("#uptAreaPRE1").val(item1);
  $("#uptAreaPRE2").val(item2);


}
```

Comment: En mi humilde opinión, si estás usando `createTemplateFromFile` no tiene sentido que el que usar `windows.onload` para llamar `google.script.run`, en su lugar usa scriptlets. En la documentación oficial se incluyen ejemplos sencillos pero completos. -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates. Por otro lado tampoco veo que tenga sentido usar jQuery todo el tiempo. En cualquier caso si requieres una orientación más precisa agrega un [mcve].

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Rubén, mi propósito consiste en pintar desde mi base de datos MySql las tablas cada una en un html diferente, soy nuevo en el mundo del desarrollo por ello las inconsciencias, lo que busco es la manera más óptima de pintar mis tablas ya que son bastantes.

Comment: Una de las habilidades básicas, y que es conveniente en ser de la primeras en poner atención, es el de ser capaz de crear un [mcve]. En relación a esto, en el código de la pregunta aparentemente sale sobrando `getTemplate` pues no es llamada en ninguna otra parte del código, por otro lado, en el caso de Google Apps Script es importante que indiques el nombre del archivo en el que se encuentra cada parte del código e incluyas todo lo que incluye el archivo. Recuerda, estamos hablando de que debe ser un [mcve]

Comment: Si en tu archivo HTML vas a usar jQuery, debes incluir la línea en la que cargas esta librería. También debes incluir cada una de las etiquetas HTML que sean requeridas por JavaScript incluido en el HTML

Comment: Si no vas a incluir scriptlets, en lugar de `createTemplateFromFile` usa `createHtmlOutputFromFile`

Comment: Preguntas relacionadas [Pasar valor de parámetro desde url hasta html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13811/65), [Botón que hace ejecutar una Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/99483/65)

Comment: Rubén, he leído atentamente cada recomendación y las preguntas relacionadas, procederé a realizar los cambios y estaré modificando mi pregunta de requerir nuevamente ayuda, mil gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si no vas a hacer uso de scriptlets, en lugar de `createTemplateFromFile` usa `createHtmlOutputFromFile`

Observaciones adicionales:

Aparentemente sale sobrando `getTemplate` pues no es llamada en ninguna otra parte del código.

En el siguiente código llamas `readAreaPRE` pero este no se incluye en la pregunta

```
window.onload = function () {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(run_This_On_Success)
        .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .readAreaPRE();
};
```

Como se mencioné en comentarios el código está incompleto como para darte una respuesta más específica.

Relacionado

- [Pasar valor de parámetro desde url hasta html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13811/65)
- [Botón que hace ejecutar una Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/99483/65)