# Spinner en Google App Scripts - HTML y GS

Tags: javascript, aplicación-web, google-apps-script

empecé hace poco con Google app Scripts y estoy teniendo un inconveniente, hice algunas herramientas que utilizo para mi trabajo, y lo que quiero hacer es que cuando mi script .gs empiece a ejecutarse, desaparezca todo el contenido del HTML y después vuelva a aparecer una vez que la tarea del script esté finalizada.
Puedo hacer que desaparezca el HTML y deje solo al spinner girando, pero una vez terminada la tarea no logro hacer que vuelva el HTML y el spinner desaparezca.
Intenté hacerlo de varias maneras y busco en internet pero no encuentro como hacerlo, si llamar al spinner desde el .gs o hacerlo en un script dentro del HTML, agradecería la ayuda.

````
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

 

    <script>
    function sample() { 
   
   var contenedor = document.getElementById("container");
   contenedor.style.visibility = "hidden";
   var spin = document.getElementById("spin");
    spin.style.visibility = "visible";
   
   var sourceFolderID = document.getElementById("docID").value;

    
   google.script.run.countSentences(sourceFolderID);  
        
  }
    </script>
</head>



<div class="container" id="container">
    <img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=1GnLjJ6Cq7U_ZKIGmeBB6jioExb8Wh4Ak" alt="FluentForever">
    <h1> Count Sentences</h1>
    <div class="datos">
        <form>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="folderID">Source Folder ID:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="docID" placeholder="Copy/Paste Folder ID from URL">
  </div>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="sample()" btn-sm>Start Counting</button>
                <div class="spinner-border text-primary text-center" role="status" id="spin" style="width: 3rem; height: 3rem;">
  <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
   <script>
    var spin = document.getElementById("spin");
    spin.style.visibility = "hidden";
    </script>
</div>
</div>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>




</body>

</html>  ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.script.run` funciona de manera asíncrona, esto quiere decir que la siguiente ínea de código (en este caso no hay ninguna) se ejecutaría sin esperar a que la función del lado de servidor, en este caso `countSentences(sourceFolderID)` termine de ejecutarse.

Para recibir el resultado o mensaje de error debes usar los métodos `withSuccessHandler` y `withFailureHandler` the `google.script.run`

```
google.script.run
.withSuccessHandler(successHandler)
.withFailureHandler(failureHandler)
.countSentences(sourceFolderID);
```

`successHandler` y `failureHandler` son callbacks, es decir, funciones que se ejecturan cuando termine, en este caso `countSentences` ya sea de forma exitosa o por causa de un error, respectivamente.

Relacionado

- [Pasar valor de parámetro desde url hasta html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13811/65)
- [Botón que hace ejecutar una Google Apps Script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/99483/65)

También relacionado

- [Cómo renderizar varias listas html con Apps Script?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/353408/65)

Recursos:

- [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!, logré hacer lo que quería, te lo agradezco un montón.